# React TypeScript Modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, state

Modal.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Modal.css'

interface IProps {
    show?: boolean;
    handleClose?: any;
    children: any;
};

const Modal:React.SFC<IProps> = ({ handleClose, show, children }: IProps) => {
    const showHideClassName = show ? "display-block" : "display-none";
    return <div className={showHideClassName}>
        <section className="modal-main">
          {children}
            <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
        </section>
      </div>;
};

export default Modal;
```

infoPresenter.tsx

```
import { Icon } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import Modal from '../Modal';
import './Info.css';

class Info extends React.Component{

  public state = {
    show: false
  };

  public showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show:true })
  }

  public hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show:false })
  }

  public render(){
    return (
      <section className="Info">
        <div className="InfoTitle">
          <h1>Philociphy</h1>
          <p>
            lorem ipsum
      </p>
        </div>
        <div className="WholeBox">
          <div className="BoxLeft" onClick={this.showModal}>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal}>
                <p>Modal</p>
                <p>Data</p>
              </Modal>
            <p>VISION</p>
            <Icon type="arrow-left" />
          </div>

          <div className="BoxRight">
            <p>VALUE</p>
            <Icon type="arrow-right" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  )
  }
}

 export default Info;
```

I want to make the modal. it works but not vanish.
I checked all my state and props, but couldn't find problems. 
I don't know where's wrong in my code.

please find it and fix it.
if you have more good idea which make the modal, please let me know how make it in typescript react.

Thanks for all guys who watch this questions

Comment: is the state getting updated when you call `hideModal` ?

Comment: Can you show me as code? Cuz I'm newbie  in React, Typescript.

Comment: add `debugger` inside `public hideModal = () => { debugger;
    this.setState({ show:false })
  }`  and check whether the state is updated when you close the modal